# trying to have a jQuery, javascript, click function which changes an image to the related id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, function

I have a vertically divided page, down the middle. On one side I have a list of restaurants, I would like when/if a name of a restaurant is clicked on, an image of the restaurant and a description appears inside a div that is on the other side of the divided page.

I am trying to do this with jQuery and have it so when there is a click event the id of the name clicked is stored in a variable and then that variable corresponds to a picture which will then be displayed in the div.

I am sure there is simpler way to do this, and I am drawing a blank on this, or if someone could help me in doing it in the way I am trying, it would be greatly appreciated. All insight is welcomed and thank you.

This is new to me. I know i could do it by going through each id and having its own function call but I am trying to be less repetitive and have a function that works for all. thanks

JS CODE :

```
$('.hover').click( function(){
   var iD = $(this).attr(id);
   $('.pictureofeats').removeAttr("id");
   $('.pictureofeats').attr('id', iD);
});
```

HTML CODE :

```
<div class="row drinks brunchpic">
   <img src="pics/buffalofood.png"   width="200px"/>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 lists">
         <ul>
            <li class="hover" id="coles">Coles</li>
            <br>
            <li class="hover" id="716">716 (Food and Sports)</li>
            <br>
            <li class="hover" id="bdb">Big Ditch Brewing</li>
            <br>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 lists">
         <ul>
            <li class="hover" id="barbill">Bar Bill</li>
            <br>
            <li class="hover" id="lloyds">Lloyds</li>
            <br>
            <li class="hover" id="abv">Allen Burger Venture</li>
            <br>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" id="foodInfo">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="pictureofeats" id="foodImg"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: There's so much wrong with this code... 1. make your whole container clickable instead of only the list items. 2. do not use classes as generic as "hover" for business logic. 3. your three-line onClick function does effectively: `$('.pictureofeats').attr('id', $(this).attr(id));` whereas you probably rather want to select the `img` element and change its `src`.

Comment: Please also show us the `.pictureofeats` HTML and how you are trying to change the image.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for looking at this and giving me some insight, @HubertGrzeskowiak .. what I was attempting was foreach name of a restaurant essentially to be its own clickable event and when one is clicked it changes the image in the div=pictureofeats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the required classname in the data-id attribute for the restaurant name
and toggle the display for the images keeping the positioned as absolute

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnb33ocy/)

Structure your HTML as following:

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="a">
  <div class="img1 active">
  1
  </div>
  <div class="img2">
  2
  </div>
  <div class="img3">
  3
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="b">
  <div data-id="img1">abc</div>
  <div data-id="img2">def</div>
  <div data-id="img3">ghi</div>
 </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
 width: 100%;  
}

.a,.b {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 48%;

}
.img1,.img2,.img3 {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.b div').click(function() {
 var x = $(this).data('id');
 $('.a div').removeClass('active');
 $('div.' + x).addClass('active');
})
```

Comment: thank you for this answer, I got it working on the page now, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
             <div id="restId" class="row drinks brunchpic"><img src="pics/buffalofood.png"  width="200px"/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 lists">
                            <ul>
                               <li class="hover" id="coles">Coles</li><br>
                                <li class="hover" id="716">716 (Food and Sports)</li><br>
                                <li class="hover" id="bdb">Big Ditch Brewing</li><br>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 lists">
                            <ul>
                               <li class="hover" id="barbill">Bar Bill</li><br>
                                <li class="hover" id="lloyds">Lloyds</li><br>
                                <li class="hover" id="abv">Allen Burger Venture</li><br>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and in javascript:

```
$('#restId').click( function(){
                    $('#restId img').attr('src', newSource);

                });
```

I think this is the logic